Transformation and image of a plane under a given transformation when one of the variables is constant.
Consider the transformation given by:
\begin{cases}
x = \frac{\sin(\sigma)\cos(\phi)}{\cosh(\tau) - \cos(\sigma)} \\
y = \frac{\sin(\sigma)\sin(\phi)}{\cosh(\tau) - \cos(\sigma)} \\
z = \frac{\sinh(\tau)}{\cosh(\tau) - \cos(\sigma)}
\end{cases}
Let $(x, y, z) = f(\sigma, \tau, \phi)$ represent this transformation.
Determine the surface equation of the image of the plane $\sigma = c$ under this transformation.
Solution: $z^2 + \left(\sqrt{x^2 + y^2} - \cot(\sigma)\right)^2 = \frac{1}{\sin^2(\sigma)}$
I've already tried squaring each component and adding them together to see if I can algebraically manipulate the equation to find something, but it didn't work out. 
If someone could help me with this problem, I would be grateful.

I would suggest you elaborate on the question since there is no clear request for what it is you need to solve for.
